# Canvas measureText() giving wrong values

Tags: javascript

I"m using measureText() to display text one char at a time and it's givng me wrong values.

I have a function drawChar(ch) that draws a character, a context "ctx", and a variable "cursor" that positions the char on the canvas:

```
var cursor = 0;

function drawChar(ch) 
{
    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    ctx.font = "20px System";
    var twidth = ctx.measureText(ch).width;
    ctx.fillText(ch, cursor*twidth, 20);
}
```

I have a global variable "letters" that I split at the beginning to get an array of letter strings:

```
 var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
 letters = letters.split("");
```

I call the function like this:

```
 drawChar(letters[cursor++]);
```

It displays the char correctly aligned at the first 2-3 chars, but then measureText() returns huge values and the chars are scattered on the canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: That's because every letter has different `width` value. They can't be positioned straight next to each other. That won't work this way.

Comment: Instead of `cursor*twidth` you'll have to sum the width of all the letters that were drawn before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because every letter has different width value. They can't be positioned straight next to each other. That won't work this way.

## Using measureText

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.append(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 450;
canvas.height = 100;
var cursor = 0;

function drawChar(ch) {
  ctx.font = "20px System";
  var twidth = ctx.measureText(ch).width;
  ctx.fillText(ch, cursor * twidth, 20);
}

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
letters = letters.split("");

for(cursor = 0; cursor < letters.length; cursor++) {
  drawChar(letters[cursor]);
}
```

## Without measureText, static value

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.append(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 450;
canvas.height = 100;
var cursor = 0;
var twidth = 15;

function drawChar(ch) {
  ctx.font = "20px System";
  ctx.fillText(ch, cursor * twidth, 20);
}

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
letters = letters.split("");

for(cursor = 0; cursor < letters.length; cursor++) {
  drawChar(letters[cursor]);
}
```

## The way to do it

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.append(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 450;
canvas.height = 100;
var cursor = 0;

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
letters = letters.split("");

function drawChar(ch) {
  ctx.font = "20px System";
  var twidth = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cursor; i++) {
    twidth += ctx.measureText(letters[i]).width;
  }
  ctx.fillText(ch, twidth, 20);
}

for(cursor = 0; cursor < letters.length; cursor++) {
  drawChar(letters[cursor]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was the different size values that were causing problems but I wasnt sure about how to implement it.